# Nested in XML pass to gridview (parent and child) using webservice in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, gridview

is there any way for Nested in XML pass to nested datagridview (parent and child) using webservice in C# (web or desktop app), i get the result simply extract data from xml and populate the grid but nested , i dont have idea.

```
<DEPARTMENT_SEARCH_RESPONSE>
  <DEPARTMENTS>
    <DEPARTMENT DepartmentID="1" Department_NAME="IT Department">
      <EMPLOYEES>
        <EMPLOYEE>
          <EMPLOYEEID>961874</EMPLOYEEID>
          <EMPLOYEE_NAME>Masood Virk</EMPLOYEE_NAME>
          <DESIGNATION>Analyst</DESIGNATION>
          <EMPLOYEE_STATUS>Active</EMPLOYEE_STATUS>
        </EMPLOYEE>
        <EMPLOYEE>
          <EMPLOYEEID>961875</EMPLOYEEID>
          <EMPLOYEE_NAME>Mubashir</EMPLOYEE_NAME>
          <DESIGNATION>Programmer</DESIGNATION>
          <EMPLOYEE_STATUS>Resign</EMPLOYEE_STATUS>
        </EMPLOYEE>
      </EMPLOYEES>
    </DEPARTMENT>

    <DEPARTMENT DepartmentID="2" Department_NAME="HR Department">
      <EMPLOYEES>
        <EMPLOYEE>
          <EMPLOYEEID>964</EMPLOYEEID>
          <EMPLOYEE_NAME>Adeel Malik </EMPLOYEE_NAME>
          <DESIGNATION>OD Officer</DESIGNATION>
          <EMPLOYEE_STATUS>Active</EMPLOYEE_STATUS>
        </EMPLOYEE>
        <EMPLOYEE>
          <EMPLOYEEID>9615</EMPLOYEEID>
          <EMPLOYEE_NAME>Aamir</EMPLOYEE_NAME>
          <DESIGNATION>Assistant</DESIGNATION>
          <EMPLOYEE_STATUS>Resign</EMPLOYEE_STATUS>
        </EMPLOYEE>
      </EMPLOYEES>
    </DEPARTMENT>
 </DEPARTMENTS>
</DEPARTMENT_SEARCH_RESPONSE>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(Server.MapPath(@"C:\Users\iht\Downloads\EvaluationTask\XmlTest.xml");

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("DEPARTMENTS/EMPLOYEES");

DataGridView.DataSource = nodes;

DataGridView.DataBind();